# Robot Framework "Select From List by Label" selects item but loses the selection

Tags: robotframework

Using Robot Framework, I have a dropdown with multiple options. When I use the `select from list by label` it selects the options, but as soon as Robot fills a text field, both selections go back to default state.

[this is the selection of dropdown list][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/laqzf.png

[this is the selection being lost after filling the text field][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVk3U.png

I'm using the following commands:

```
select from list by label    xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Complexidade'])[1]/following::select[1]     Complexo
sleep    2s
select from list by label   xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='SIEM'])[1]/following::select[1]     Microsoft Azure Sentinel
sleep    2s
set focus to element    xpath=//div[@id='app']/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[9]/textarea
press keys    xpath=//div[@id='app']/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[9]/textarea     R
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem with robotframework? What happens if you do it manually?

Comment: When I do it manually, it works perfectly :-)

Comment: You could try clicking the textfield instead of setting focus to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Press Keys, you should use [Input Text](https://rpaframework.org/libdoc/RPA_Browser_Selenium.html#Input%20Text) to enter the text in a text field.

```
Input Text    xpath    text_to_enter
```

Working code

```
select from list by label    xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Complexidade'])[1]/following::select[1]     Complexo
sleep    2s
select from list by label   xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='SIEM'])[1]/following::select[1]     Microsoft Azure Sentinel
sleep    2s
Input Text   xpath=//div[@id='app']/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[9]/textarea     R
```